# Ical format import to the Google calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api, icalendar

I have *.ics file. Where I have one event with one attendee but the event was imported but the attendee was not. What did I do wrong?

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//github.com/rianjs/ical.net//NONSGML ical.net 4.0//EN
VERSION:4.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
ATTENDEE;CN=Martin Gabrle;RSVP=TRUE:mailto:martin.gabrle@daktela.com
DTSTART:20230202T060000Z
DTEND:20230202T070000Z
DTSTAMP:20230130T120027Z
SEQUENCE:0
UID:5489af48-6ccb-4ad6-aa33-39db4d549c49
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

I tried to export the event from google calendar. I changed the uid and imported it back, but the attendees weren't there either.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, this is not possible in google calendar:

> You can transfer your events from a different calendar application or Google Account to Google Calendar.
> When you import an event, guests and conference data for that event are not imported.

[source](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37118?h)

The export includes attendees but the import does not, to my knowledge the API does support adding them.